# Standard deployment descriptor web.xml for Java EE 8 returns error

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, netbeans-8.2, glassfish-5

I am trying to write a small web application with the new Java EE 8 in a NetBeans 8.2 IDE. I set up a web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"> 
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
      30
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

If I am trying to validate the XML file I get the following error

> XML validation started. Checking
>   file:/Users/xxx/Development/projects/TestTrial/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml...
>   Referenced entity at
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd". Vorzeitiges
>   Dateiende. [1] http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd XML
>   validation finished.

Which tells me, that there is a preliminary end of file. If I change it from 4.0 to 3.1 everthing works fine.
The following software was used NetBeans 8.2 / JDK 1.8u152 / glassfish v5

I am pretty new to Java EE and help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your servlet version?

Comment: I am using javaee-api-8.0.jar, so I guessed it should be servlet 4.0. Is there another way of figuring it out? And where does it affect XML validation, I thought it checks just the XML file.

Comment: I'm exploring the same issue but things are little bit weird. Should we change web.xml descriptors or do we need to keep them like for JEE7? JEE8 samples show old one https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee8-samples/blob/master/servlet/http2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml